# Django - AtributeError: module object has no attribute STATIC_URL

Tags: django, debugging, static, media

I have project which consists of three different apps. They use general `settings.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

SECRET_KEY = '123456'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)



INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)


EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"
SENDGRID_API_KEY = "*******"

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),
    )
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS': 'default',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS': '300',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX': '',
    }
}

PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

as you can see - nothing special in there. Each app has it's additional `app#_settings.py` file which extends general `settings.py`.

All of these apps have this (last) line in their `urls.py`:

```
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I'm in development mode, with DEBUG set to True. APP1 and APP2 are able to run development server, while i have problem with third APP and last two days i'm trying to figure out what the heck could be the problem, but without success. When i run development server (with `runserver --settings=app3_settings`) i get this error:

```
AtributeError: module object has no attribute STATIC_URL
```

Here is `app3_settings.py`: (app1 and app2 have pretty similar settings, almost no difference)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from settings import * 

SECRET_KEY = '*************************************************'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost', 
    '127.0.0.1',
    ]

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'storages',
    'app3',
    'el_pagination',
    'debug_toolbar',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app3.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app3.wsgi.application'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'web@example.com'

MANAGERS = ADMINS

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS': 'default',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS': '300',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX': '',
    }
}

PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
)


# AMAZON S3 & CLOUDFRONT SERVING MEDIA FILES
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN = 'example.cloudfront.net'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "*************"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "************************"
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'app3/media'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/%s/' % MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
MEDIA_URL = '//%s/%s/' % (AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app3.custom_storages.MediaStorage'

# WHITENOISE SERVING STATIC FILES
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/static/app3') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

As you can see i have declared STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT correctly. I emphasize again - **APP1 & APP2 use absolutely the same concept, but i do not get this error while trying to run development server with them**, so i don't get this.

I tried to copy this part of `app3_settings.py` to `settings.py`:

```
# AMAZON S3 & CLOUDFRONT SERVING MEDIA FILES
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN = 'example.cloudfront.net'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "*************"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "************************"
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'app3/media'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/%s/' % MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
MEDIA_URL = '//%s/%s/' % (AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app3.custom_storages.MediaStorage'

# WHITENOISE SERVING STATIC FILES
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/static/app3') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and then server is able to start. But i'm not sure why should i have to repeat these lines in `settings.py` and in `app#_settings.py` when app1 and app2 use same settings and they work with no problem.

If it matters, here is `manage.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Also, i have separate `wsgi.py` for each app and it looks like this ('app#_settings' is the only difference between apps):

```
import os
import sys
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
sys.path.append('/home/user/public_html/project')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app#_settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: I suspect you are importing the wrong `settings` module in APP3's `urls`. It looks that `app3_settings` is ignored and Django is reading default `settings` module. Might be because of slight structural difference in APP3 layout.

Comment: from django.conf import settings, same as in other apps' urls files.

Comment: Edit in wsgi.py  `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app3.app3_settings'` and try with `runserver --settings=app3.app3_settings`

Comment: I've done as you suggested but it shows an error `ImportError: No module named app3_settings`. I think it's because `settings.py`,`app1_settings.py`,`app2_settings.py` and `app3_settings.py` are in the root of the project and `app3.app3_settings` would look for that file in the app3 folder (not in the root folder).

Comment: Right, in `urls.py` try: `import settings` instead of `from django.conf import settings`.

Comment: Unfortunately i still get `ImportError: No module named app3_settings`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116309/discussion-between-purrogrammer-and-ljubisa-livac).